# Nutch problems executing crawl

Tags: apache, lucene, nutch

I am trying to get nutch 1.11 to execute a crawl.  I am using cygwin to run these commands in windows 7.

Nutch is running, I am getting results from running bin/nutch, but I keep getting error messages when I try to run a crawl.

I am getting the following error when I try to run a crawl execute with nutch:

Error running: /cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject TestCrawl/crawldb C:/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/urls/seed.txt

Failed with exit value 127.

I have my JAVA_HOME classpath set, and I have altered the host file to include the 127.0.0.1 as the localhost.

I am curious if I am calling the write directory correctly, if maybe that is the problem.

The full printout looks like:

```
User5@User5-PC /cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local
$ bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/ C:/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/urls/ TestCrawl/  2

Injecting seed URLs
/cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject TestCrawl//crawldb C:/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/urls/
Injector: starting at 2015-12-23 17:48:21
Injector: crawlDb: TestCrawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: C:/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:421)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.mkdirs(FilterFileSystem.java:281)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(JobSubmissionFiles.java:125)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:348)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1285)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1282)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1282)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:833)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:323)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:379)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)

Error running:
  /cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject TestCrawl//crawldb C:/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/urls/
Failed with exit value 127.
```

The hadoop log that I think may have something to do with the error I am getting is:

```
2016-01-07 12:24:40,360 ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getQualifiedBinPath(Shell.java:318)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.getWinUtilsPath(Shell.java:333)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:326)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.preProcessForWindows(GenericOptionsParser.java:432)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)
2016-01-07 12:24:40,450 ERROR crawl.Injector - Injector: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 15: solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:172)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 15: solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3048)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:746)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.initialize(Path.java:203)
    ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running linux commands from `Cygwin` and there is no `C:\` path in linux systems. Correct command should be something like

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch1.11/runtime/local/bin/nutch inject TestCrawl/crawldb /cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch1.11/runtime/local/urls/seed.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with that mistake of mine; I didn't realize I was doing that.

Comment: @JerrittPace You are welcome. Please select my answer as the best answer if helped you. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry I tried to edit that but I didn't get it done right;  I really appreciate the help, and I believe the error I was making will cause problems, but I am still getting the same error with the revised command, as well as just a bare command without the explicit call to the directory: bin/crawl -i -D solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr urls TestCrawl 2;  bin/crawl -i -D /cygdrive/c/Users/User5/Documents/Nutch/apache-nutch-1.11/runtime/local/urls/ solr.server.url=http://localhost:8983/solr/ TestCrawl/ 2; these both return the same error:  Failed with exit value 127.

Comment: I want to revise the original question to include the hadoop log

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea what I am doing wrong, and I have left messages at a host of forums, and yours is the first answer I have received, and I really appreciate the insight.  I don't know what I am doing wrong, but nearly everything I have tried gives me this error.  I just cannot seem to make the "crawl" command work

Comment: @JerrittPace I got confused. Are you getting the same error? but your question edited with a new error.

Answer (score 0):

You have answer to your problem in this message:

> 2016-01-07 12:24:40,360 ERROR util.Shell - Failed to locate the winutils binary in the hadoop binary path
>   java.io.IOException: Could not locate executable null\bin\winutils.exe in the Hadoop binaries.

This is happening because hadoop version included with nutch 1.11 is designed to work in linux out of the box and not on windows.

I had same situation and I ended up using nutch1.11 in ubuntu virtual box.

Answer (score 0):

> `hadoop-core` jar file is needed when you are working with nutch

- with nutch 1.11 compatible hadoop-core jar is 0.20.0
- > please download jar from this link :
  >   http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0200corejar.htm
- > paste that jar into `"C:\cygwin64\home\apache-nutch-1.11\lib"` folder
  >   and it will run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty clear. According to your hadoop log, it cannnot find the winutils.exe file. Include winutils.exe in %HADOOP_HOME%/bin folder