# Nutch 1.12 on Cygwin on Windows

Tags: nutch

English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.

I try to run nutch 1.12 on Cygwin on Windows, and I followed [Nutch Turorial](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial). But when I try execute the command line "bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls", I get this in Cygwin:

```
$ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls
Injector: starting at 2017-03-10 19:29:00
Injector: crawlDb: crawl/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:445)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:418)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:650)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:633)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.setPermission(FilterFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:424)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:906)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:887)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createNewFile(FileSystem.java:1149)
    at org.apache.nutch.util.LockUtil.createLockFile(LockUtil.java:58)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.inject(Injector.java:357)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.run(Injector.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:441)
```

I have tried the methods mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36615898/4814119) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36615898/4814119), but either worked for me.

How can I solve this problem and run Nutch on Windows?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved it by setting up Hadoop and including winutils.exe in `%HADOOP_HOME%/bin` folder. If there is still the same error try including hadoop.dll inside the mentioned folder.